# Convert a list of Sparse Matrices into a Single Sparse Matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am looking to take (non-sparse example):

```
[1 1 1
 1 1 1
 1 1 1]

[2 2 2
 2 2 2
 2 2 2]
```

And get

```
[1 1 1
 1 1 1
 1 1 1
 2 2 2
 2 2 2
 2 2 2]
```

I think this is called a concatenation? I am using csr_matrix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python how to combine two matrices in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180210/python-how-to-combine-two-matrices-in-numpy)

Comment: For `numpy` arrays there's `np.concatenate` and a group of 'stack' functions that use it.  For sparse, there's `sparse.vstack` and `sparse.hstack`.  Both use the spare `bmat` operation, which combines the the `coo` attributes of the matrices.