# How to insert a matrix into another matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I'm trying to create a function to insert a matrix in an another(square matrix), for example:

```
A = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)]
B = [(2,4),(6,8)]

C = funcmatrix(A,B)

result: [1 2 3 0 0
         4 5 6 0 0
         7 8 9 0 0
         0 0 0 2 4
         0 0 0 6 8]
```

Comment: Using numpy? Python lists..?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: look to these answers  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180210/python-how-to-combine-two-matrices-in-numpy

Comment: [scipy.linalg.block_diag(A, B)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.block_diag.html) does exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)])
B = np.array([(2,4),(6,8)])

combined = np.block([[A, np.zeros((len(A), len(B)))], 
                     [np.zeros((len(B), len(A))), B]])
```

Out:

```
array([[1., 2., 3., 0., 0.],
       [4., 5., 6., 0., 0.],
       [7., 8., 9., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 2., 4.],
       [0., 0., 0., 6., 8.]])
```

Please refer to [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.block.html).

Answer (score 0):

An another approach using numpy I found:

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
B = np.array([[2,4],[6,8]])
```

```
bshape = B.shape
ashape = A.shape

a=np.append(A,np.zeros((bshape[0],ashape[0])),axis=0)
b=np.append(np.zeros((ashape[0],bshape[0])),B,axis=0)
```

Now append them together:

```
np.append(a,b,axis=-1)
```

I hope this will work on your case

Answer (score 0):

As per *scleronomic*'s comment, [block_diag](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.block_diag.html) should do the trick:

```
A = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)]
B = [(2,4),(6,8)]

import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import block_diag

block_diag(np.array(A), np.array(B))
```

gives:

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 0],
       [4, 5, 6, 0, 0],
       [7, 8, 9, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 2, 4],
       [0, 0, 0, 6, 8]])
```