# Joining two numpy matrices into one

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy matrices and I want to join them together like:

```
[[1, 2],          [[7, 8],             [[[1, 2],
 [3, 4],    +      [9, 10],     =        [7, 8]],
 [5, 6]]           [11, 12]]            [[3, 4],
                                         [9, 10]],
                                        [[5, 6],
                                         [11, 12]]]
```

I don't know how to do that. Please help me.

Comment: What you want is called concatenation or stacking, search With these terms and you’ll find an answer.

Comment: check if this works for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180210/python-how-to-combine-two-matrices-in-numpy

Comment: I think np.stack with axis=1

Answer (score 1):

Do it in this way:

```
mat1=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
mat2=[[7,8],[9,10],[11,12]]
final_mat=[]
for i in zip(mat1,mat2):
    final_mat.append(list(i))
print(final_mat)
```

Output:

```
[[[1, 2], [7, 8]], [[3, 4], [9, 10]], [[5, 6], [11, 12]]]
```